# Mark packets from specific user on LAN

Tags: networking, vpn

I have a Debian based VPN router setup.  Some websites don't like the VPN, so sometimes
I need to bypass the VPN.  I setup a Policy Based Routing table for a specific user on the router, and that works fine.  In order to browse and bypass the VPN, I use Remmina to RDP into the router machine from a user machine on the LAN and then use my browser in the RDP session.  That's okay, but it is a little cumbersome - although I don't bypass the VPN much at all.

I was looking for another solution whereby I can use one of the user machines on my LAN rather than RDP'ing via Remmina onto the router.  I was thinking I could use an iptables
rule with "-m owner --uid-owner" to mark the packets.  I tried this but couldn't get it to work - it seemed that the LAN traffic never got marked.

---

My question is:
Do packets coming across the LAN have an associated UID, or is that only for traffic on
the "local" machine?

---

If the answer is "no", traffic across the LAN does not have a UID associated, then is
there another solution to having a user on the LAN bypass the VPN?

My current solution is working okay, but I'm really intrigued by the power of routing tables and Policy Based Routing.  At this point it is a learning exercise for me that
keeps me thinking.

---

HA, HA!  Like this website!  I tried to post this question, but couldn't - presumably because my VPN traffic "looked like spam".  I am now "bypassing" VPN with Remmina and
will try again.

Comment: IP packets **never** have an associated UID.  The kernel on the sending machine, or a root-owned process, however, either already "knows" or can find the PID that sent the packet (or is waiting for a response) and backtrack from that to the UID and/or GID that owns the process.   Which is how `iptables -m owner` rules can work.

Comment: Marking packets with `iptables` is probably the way to go (if your router can handle that), otherwise you might want to use different private IP addresses and source-routing.  Packets with, say, 192.168.0.1 as the source address go via the VPN while packages with 192.168.0.2 bypass the VPN and get masqueraded normally.